# Hiberatne try to create table for View Entity

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

**Hello.**
Please can you tell me it is possible to disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update but for one class (entity). I would like hibernate to create tables for all entities except one which is synonymous to the view in other schema.

> @Entity @Immutable

Don't work - hibernate still try to create table.

Thansk for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got this.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.synonyms=true

This resolve my problem.